# Количество элементов с одинаковым классом

Tags: jquery, javascript

У меня на странице какое-то количество элементов с одинаковым классом. Как узнать сколько их, используя js или jquery?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

jQuery

```
$('.someClass').length
```

js

```
document.getElementsByClassName('someClass').length
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
console.log($('div').length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Я делаю с недавних пор так:

```js
var texts = document.querySelectorAll(".slider .subslider"),
suball = texts.length;
$('span').append(suball);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="subslider">0</div>
</div>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="subslider">1</div>
</div>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="subslider">2</div>
  <div class="subslider">3</div>
  <div class="subslider">4</div>
</div>
<span>Количество: </span>
```

При этом, если элементы разбросаны по всей странице, и надо не просто их посчитать, а порядок сохранить. Делаю так:

```js
  var texts = document.querySelectorAll(".slider .subslider"),
    suball = texts.length,
    arrtext = Array.from(texts);
    $('span').append(suball);
    var i = 0;
    for(; i < suball; i++){
      var co = i;
      $(arrtext[co]).append(co);
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="subslider">0 Suball: </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="subslider">1 Suball: </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider">
      <div>
        <div class="subslider">2 Suball: </div>
        <div class="subslider">3 Suball: </div>
      </div>
      <div class="subslider">4 Suball: </div>
    </div>
    <span>Количество: </span>
```

На jQuery я так и не нашёл как это делать, только набор внутри одного родителя, другой считается новым. По крайней мере я с этой проблемой сталкивался года три назад. Мне нужно было посчитать общее количество элементов, разбросанных по странице, и вывести их порядок.....
Да, может где-то сглупил, или во всём, но я только пользователь JS, а не разработчик на нём. А на чистом - самый простой способ что я нашёл уже спустя столько времени.

Answer (score 2):

На jQuery еще так можно

```
var count = $('.someClass').size();
 alert(count);
```

Comment: о да, учитывая, что `size` deprecated и на самом деле просто возвращает `length` [пруф.](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L181)

Comment: всмысле? size криво работает или что?)

Comment: в 9 случаях из девяти используйте `.length`

Comment: ну ок)) 
буду юзать)